# Создание таблицы в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, table, richtextbox

Как создать таблицу в `RichTextBox`? Нужно чтобы по нажатию на `Button` создалась таблица 2x1, но если нажать на Enter (как и в Word) добавится еще одна строка, а если два раза нажать на Enter то таблица закроется и просто продолжаем писать текст.

Comment: Встроенных средств для такого нету, вам придётся всё программировать самостоятельно.

Comment: Где-то видел что можно готовые таблицы из Word вставлять. Вроде файл Word с таблицей в папку с проектом помещается и делается ссылка на него. Так можно?

Comment: Вроде бы да, RichTextBox поддерживает RTF как входной формат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Руководствуясь [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13321729/5045688) ответом, можно поступить так.

Определяем заготовку таблицы с одной строкой и двумя ячейками:

```
string table = @"\trowd\cellx1000\cellx2000\intbl \cell\intbl \cell\row";
```

Код добавления таблицы в `RichTextBox`:

```
int index = richTextBox.Rtf.LastIndexOf("}");
richTextBox.Rtf = richTextBox.Rtf.Substring(0, index) + table + "}";
```